# Router throughput concern

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, wired-networking

I'm hosting LAN party and I am concerned about networking. Everyone will be connected on wire to switch. There will be multiple switches (4x 24/48 port) and I am thinking about wiring these switches to edge router. The reason is DHCP, I expect up to 100 people so it would be pain to set static IPs on all devices.

Folder sharing etc will be **prohibited**. The router **wont** be connected to internet. I want to use this router for DHCP only, QoS is welcome

Will the router handle all the bandwidth? Do you know some other solutions to not set static IPs on each device? Thanks a lot!

PS: Similiar router I want to plug-in: TP-Link Archer C6

Comment: How many subnets will you be creating? Will all clients be wired (Ethernet) and not Wi-Fi?

Comment: You want to use the router as single-scoped (one subnet) DHCP server only? or you want to handle a lot of DHCP servers with separate subnets/scopes and route all traffic between subnets by the router?

Comment: *Similiar router I want to plug-in: **TP-Link Archer C6*** This router may handle only one IP address pool ([documentation](https://www.tp-link.com/en/user-guides/Archer-A6&C6_V2/chapter-12-customize-your-network-settings#ug-sub-title-2)). So the only option is that all users will obtain IP addresses from the same subnet, they will access to each other directly, and they do not need in routing. So your router's bandwidth makes no sense.

Comment: *Folder sharing etc will be prohibited. The router wont be connected to internet.* What services will be acessed through the LAN? maybe you do not need in it at all?

Comment: How many subnets will you be creating? 
- Only one subnet - mask /24 probably
 | 
Will all clients be wired (Ethernet) and not Wi-Fi? 
- Yes, no wifi will be provided
 | 

So in case of one subnet only, traffic wont go through router then? 
Would it be really bad idea to have router just as a DHCP server instead of some local DHCP server installed on one of the connected devices?

Comment: It literally wouldn't change anything. Yes the router's built-in DHCP server would advertise the router as a gateway to other networks... but that only applies when you actually try to access other networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all hosts are wired, thne same-subnet traffic *does not go* through the router. That is actually the whole point of a 'subnet', it means devices are accessible to each other at MAC layer (i.e. through switches only). So the router's bandwidth capabilities are irrelevant.

(Traffic between wired Ethernet and wireless Wi-Fi clients *does* go through the Wi-Fi router's or access point's "bridge", although it still is not routed but only forwarded at MAC-layer.)

The DHCP server doesn't handle data traffic, it only issues configuration, so it doesn't have to be located on a router. Indeed, if you don't need access to other networks, then you don't need a router *at all* – you can run a DHCP server on a spare laptop or on a Raspberry Pi.

Folder sharing is irrelevant to the question. It is more or less just an ordinary TCP connection between two hosts and does not have special requirements or any unusual resource usage.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I wasn't sure about the routing mechanism. The folder sharing was just fyi, because last year people were copying files through network and it caused high latency for other people playing games via LAN. I will have laptop with debian connected to this network where most of game servers will be running so I'll install dhcp server there. Thanks again folks

Comment: Depending on what else is going on you might want to have DNS running somewhere also.